# Creating a transparent panel

Tags: java, panel, transparent

I need to create a panel which should be invisible but the components inside it (for example, JTextArea, JButton, etc.) should be visible. When I click on the invisible panel, it should become visible.

I can only use JRE 1.4 and nothing more than that. :(

Any idea how to create such a transparent panel???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Transparancy is controlled with

```
setOpaque(false)
```

Comment: I was under the impression that this is considered as misuse of setOpaque - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451990/setopaquetrue-false-java

Comment: that article explains how Swing got it wrong. Doesnt make it the wrong solution.

Answer (score 5):

`JComponent.setOpaque(false)` is the way to go.