# Adding JMenu to an undecorated JFrame operating in per-pixel translucency mode does not paint

Tags: java, swing

I've added a JMenu to an undecorated JFrame and the JMenuItem is not painted until I move the mouse over the unpainted area.  Has anyone seen this problem and know how to fix/circumvent?  Here is a reduced test case showing the problem.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

public class TestCase {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new JFrame() {{
        setJMenuBar(new JMenuBar() {{
            setOpaque(true);
            add(new JMenu("ProblemMenu") {{
                setOpaque(true);
                add(new JMenuItem("NotPainted"){{
                    setOpaque(true);
                }});}});}});
        setUndecorated(true);
        setBackground(new Color(11,111,222,196));
        setSize(300,300);
        setLocation(300,300);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        getContentPane().add(new JButton(" OpaqueButton "));
        setVisible(true);
    }};
}
}
```

[image]

Click the menu "ProblemMenu" and the menu will open with a white rectangle where the JMenuItem should be located. Move the mouse over that area and the JMenuItem paints.

Comment: `}});}});}});`  ..Huh?  I for one find code a lot easier to understand when closing `}` are on their own line, and only one `{` is used per line.

Comment: Try `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to initialize your UI, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details.

Comment: agree...I did it for compactness...apply your eclipse formatter.

Comment: @max - I tried invokeLater() - no help...same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The per-pixel translucent JFrame menu paint problem was caused by the JRE and fixed by moving to a newer JRE ( 1.7.0_09-b05 ).

Answer (score 1):

It's probably setOpaque() calls in combination with your LAF.

Read this great answer for why setOpaque() is problematic.

[setOpaque(true/false); Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451990/setopaquetrue-false-java)